# How do you make links/href in CSS grid appear inline versus block?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

When I insert a link into a div container using CSS grid, it treats the link as a block element vs. inline. Even when I try to force it to be inline, it still treats it as block. How can I make a link display inline?

Thanks for your help.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 180px
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    Text with a <a href="#">link</a> in it. This is text without a link in it.
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    Text with a <a href="#" style="display: inline;">link</a> in it. This is text without a link in it.
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the above code will render as:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 4):

### Use an Element Selector Within Grid CSS

Because you've made the `<div>` a `grid` element it's treating all content inside it as `grid` also.

To jump out of this, you can wrap your content in something like a `<span>` as seen in the below code.

Anything inside these wrapper elements will default back to their default states, which is `inline` or `block` and act as normal.

You can use other element **selectors** also, such as, `<div>text</div>`, `<p>text</p>` or anything that suits your design.

[image]

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 180px
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    Text with a <a href="#">link</a> in it. This is text without a link in it.
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <span>Text with a <a href="#">link</a> in it. This is text without a link in it.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forced `.item` to be a grid box so every tag in `.item` will align as a grid element like the `<a>` so just remove from `.item` `display: grid;` because I think you will not use it as grid box but as an element of the `#container` grid.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px ;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 180px 
}
    
.item {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div class="item">
      Text with a <a href="#">link</a> in it.
      This is text without a link in it.
   </div>

   <div class="item"> 
      Text with a <a href="#">link</a> in it.
      This is text without a link in it.
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove inline for item.

```html
<style>
    #container{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 100px 100px ;
     grid-template-columns: 180px 180px;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item">
    Text with a <a href="#">link</a> in it.
    This is text without a link in it.
    </div>

    <div class="item"> 
    Text with a <a href="#" style="display: inline;">link</a> in it.
    This is text without a link in it.
    </div>
  </div>
```